# Tikzpicture double bend left nodes

Tags: tikz-trees, automata

Is there any possible way to make double bend arrows from one node to two other nodes? I now have:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=lightgray,draw=black,text=black]
\node[initial,state] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
\node[state,accepting] (q2) [right of=q1] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q3) [right of=q2] {$q_3$};
\path
(q0) edge node {a} (q1) 
(q1) edge node {b} (q2) 
(q2) edge node {a} (q3) 
(q3) edge [bend left, above] node {b} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And my figure looks like this:

[image: tikzpictures nodes]

But I would like to add another bend left node from q3 to q2:

```
(q3) edge [bend left, above] node {a} (q1)
```

If I add this piece of code, no arrow to the left from q3 to q1 is showing. How can I fix this?

Comment: please have a look at the answer below

Comment: Too bad...I thought this was going to be a question about "double dangerous bends" https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=double+dangerous+bend. +1 anyway

Comment: @Julius request accept the answer if meets  the requirement

Comment: @jsbibra what do you mean? I don't understand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\begin{document}


   \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=lightgray,draw=black,text=black]
    \node[initial,state] (q0) {$q_0$};
    \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
    \node[state,accepting] (q2) [right of=q1] {$q_2$};
    \node[state,accepting] (q3) [right of=q2] {$q_3$};
    \path
    (q0) edge node {a} (q1) 
    (q1) edge node {b} (q2) 
    (q2) edge node {a} (q3) 
    (q3) edge [bend left, above] node {b} (q2)
    (q3) edge [bend right, above] node {c} (q2)
    (q3) edge [bend left, above, pos=0.8] node {d} (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer how you can fix this since you've not shown the exact code that isn't working, but that said,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=Stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=lightgray,draw=black,text=black]
\node[initial,state] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
\node[state,accepting] (q2) [right of=q1] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q3) [right of=q2] {$q_3$};
\path
(q0) edge node {a} (q1) 
(q1) edge node {b} (q2) 
(q2) edge node {a} (q3) 
(q3) edge [bend left, above] node {a} (q1)
(q3) edge [bend left, above] node {b} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works for me and produces

[image]

so I believe the problem *may* perhaps be down to semicolon placement. If this isn't it, it would be nice if you could post a complete MWE that isn't working.

Comment: '    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=lightgray,draw=black,text=black]
\node[initial,state] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
\node[state,accepting] (q2) [right of=q1] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q3) [right of=q2] {$q_3$};
\path
(q0) edge node {a} (q1) 
(q1) edge node {b} (q2) 
(q2) edge node {a} (q3) 
(q3) edge [bend left, above] node {b} (q2) (q3) edge [bend left, above] node {b} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}'

Comment: This is the whole code, so all the code I gave in the beginning plus the line I gave at the end

Comment: So I have tried your solution, but I didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Julius Try `>=Stealth` instead of `>=stealth'` (uppercase, and no apostrophe).